# Django, can't load json file due to UNIQUE constraint

Tags: json, python-3.x, loaddata

I am new to python. I am cloning a project, and after migrating the models, I am trying to seed the database. Migrating was done with no issue.

The file I am trying to seed, is basically an array of JSON objects. For example:

```
          [
    {
                "model": "contenttypes.contenttype",
                "pk": 5,
                "fields": {
                    "app_label": "auth",
                    "model": "group"
                }
    ]
```

I am using below command to seed the data:

```
 python3 manage.py loaddata data.json
```

But, I am keeping getting the error:

```
'django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture : Could not load contenttypes.ContentType(pk=5): UNIQUE constraint failed: django_content_type.app_label, django_content_type.model'
```

I have searched a lot for similar questions, and I tried for example replacing 'pk' with 'id' (for object with contenttype, and auth.permission). However, it didn't work.

I am using Django==2.1.7, django-admin-tools==0.8.1.

I have tried this command as suggested in other questions (python3 manage.py dumpdata > data.json)...It only changed the format of the json file, and I was able to process the load data command, but the data wasn't populated.

Appreciate your support.

Comment: The error means that there's already data in the database with app_label = auth, and model = group. You can query the database to see what's already there, and remove those entries from your JSON object list.

Comment: many thanks for your support. I believe the seed file was older than the current migrations. So, after I deleted them, it is working fine...

Comment: Ah, ok. Glad you figured it out!